# IF function using dates to find if a date is between 2 dates in VB Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of dates that I an am trying to add to a schedule with dates of the week commencing in. I have tried many different things and I can't seam to work it out. No matter what I try it still comes back with an error every time. If i change the dates to numbers (e.g. 12/01/2015 to 12) it works fine.

```
'Set the start of my column number.
Col = 1

'Set it to stop when the dates stop
Do While Not IsEmpty(Range("A" & Col))
'See if the date entered is past the previous date e.g. 01/01/15
    If Cells(3, Col).Value > Cells(1, Col).Value Then
'Then see if it is before the next date e.g. 07/01/15
        If Cells(3, Col) < Cells(1, (Col + 1)).Value Then
'If both are true value ins the schedule will be "service"
            Cells(2, Col).Text = "Service"
    Col = Col + 1
'loops for next set of dates
Loop
```

Do I need to use something other than `.value` for the dates (they are entered in a dd/mm/yyyy format if that helps) or is there a function I am not aware about that I need to use in VBA in order for them to be recognised as dates?

Or as an alternative would it be better to use `DateDiff` instead of ">" and "<" to return the dates as a difference between the two dates in question. Then, find the 2 dates that both have a difference to of less than 7 to the input date and then use this to add them to the schedule? substituting the line below in the code above?

```
DiffBefore = DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, Cells(3, Col), Cells(1, Col))
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: General question: Are you looping down the spreadsheet (row by row) or across the spreadsheet (column by column)? In your `Do While` line, you've mentioned `Range("A" & col)`. Both the letter A and the `col` variable seem to reference the column.

Comment: I will be looping coloumn by coloumn. Yes that is a bit missleading I coped an older verson of things I was trying where I had made that mistake. Now it has changed to 'Cells(col, 1)' to move it coloumn by coloumn (I hope anyway).

Comment: Understood. Sometimes variable names can be confusing. RE the `Cells` function. The first value refers to the `Row`, and the second value refers to the `Column`. So, it should be `Cells(1, col)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general way to check if a date, *d3*, is between two other dates, *d1* and *d2*:

```
Public Function DateCheck(d1 As Date, d2 As Date, d3 As Date) As Boolean
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction

    If d3 >= wf.Min(d1, d2) And d3 <= wf.Max(d1, d2) Then
        DateCheck = True
    Else
        DateCheck = False
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Having a Small issue with this. When I call this fuction with a test page I made (cells D1=01/02/15, D2=10/02/15 and D3=05/02/15) I get the "Argument not opptional" error. Sorry if this is obious, I'm fairly new to VBA and have never actualt used fuctions. This is how I am trying to call the function. Call DateCheck `Sub DateCheckTEST() Call DateCheck If DateCheck = True Then MsgBox ("This Date is in this period") Else MsgBox ("This Date is not in this period") End If End Sub`